# How to accept PayPal or credit card payments within Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, credit-card, paypal

Is it possible to accept credit card payments or execute PayPal transactions within a Facebook app?

The ideal flow is for users to browse a catalog and complete a purchase all within Facebook. Is this possible?

If so, could you provide guides/tutorials for accomplishing this?

To clarify, our understanding is FB takes 30% of FB Credit purchases. We for this reason plan on offering either PayPal or credit card purchases, not FB Credit purchases. Is it possible to allow FB users to purchase with PP or CC instead of FB Credits? If we're wrong on the 30% transaction fee, please let us know. Thx!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting July 1st 2011 an app on facebook can only perform transactions with Facebook Credits (ignoring in game 'currency') . I have no idea where the doc covering this is, I'm not involved in that side of things.

This page https://developers.facebook.com/credits/ has this screen shot
[image]
which shows PayPal as an option to pay.

Here's a link from FishWorld that is explaining the policy on their forums http://www.talltreegames.com/fwf/showthread.php?3807-Facebook-Credits-Switchover-on-July-1st&p=20350#post20350

FaceBook LINKS!
https://developers.facebook.com/policy/
https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/
https://www.facebook.com/payments_terms/

Hopefully this random smattering of information is of some help to you. :)

Comment: Knew I'd read that somewhere! Good thing it supports PayPal though, so essentially you should be fine with this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anywhere listed that 'ALL' facebook apps must receive payments using Facebook credits. On the following page, https://developers.facebook.com/credits/, I see that it is mandated ONLY for GAME apps as of now.

> Quoting from the link above:
>
> Note: Effective July 1, games on Facebook Platform must exclusively process payments through > Facebook Credits. Learn more on the Migration page.

If it is not explicit, I would assume that it is not mandated.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as a regular Facebook app is no different from a website, albeit in a small`ish iframe. Sure.
I'd look at integrating the Express Checkout for Digital Goods solution for an even better checkout experience; https://www.paypal.com/digitalgoods

Note: You may still want to review the Facebook T&C's on this; I'm not entirely sure if this is allowed by them

Comment: paypal express doesnt work in the fb iframe.  have you tested this? Have a solution on how to make it work?

Comment: PayPal Express Checkout is different from PayPal Express Checkout for Digital Goods. ;-)